# How can I restrict access to an unmanaged dll to only a specific 3rd party (denying access to all others)?

Tags: c++, security, dll

I created an unmanaged C++ DLL that I'd like to provide to a 3rd-party. The DLL will be distributed publically but I don't want anyone else to be able to call methods in the DLL. What's a good way to restrict access?

FWIW - the DLL will be used on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: What's the point of giving someone a DLL they can't use?

Comment: Sorry - maybe I wasn't clear enough. I do want the library to be used by 1 company. But when they distribute it to end-users, I don't want others to be able to pick it up and use it themselves.

Comment: Maybe use a static library then. That 1 company can link it into their executable, and the end user will never see it.

Comment: Hi Ayjay -- I don't think I can do that because a) C# needs to call this and C# can't link to unmanaged static libraries AFAIK and b) my unmanaged library calls a LGPL library and LGPL states it must be linked dynamically.... but maybe if I could figure out how to statically link to my library, then the "host" app could still dynamically link to the LGPL library

Comment: I think you may be a little out of luck here then. You could use some form of obfuscation to restrict access from lazy attackers, but not from any dedicated attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you can't stop somebody who's determined, but you can do a few things to make life difficult for unauthorized users.

The obvious would be to encrypt (at least most of) the code in the DLL. Have a single entry point that the user has to call to get (for example) a table of pointers to the real functions. When the entry point is called, a key has to be supplied and that is used to decrypt the rest of the content, and then the pointers are returned. If the user supplies the wrong key, they get pointers, but the data won't be decrypted correctly, so when they try to call it, it doesn't work.

That's not foolproof by any means. Just for an obvious example, if somebody runs the authorized program under a debugger they can see what key is passed, and simply re-use it. If you want to make life a bit trickier for an attacker, you can do something like having the DLL do a checksum on the executable, and use that as the key (and the user will have to embed some data to get the checksum to come out right). That can still be figured out, but it will at least take some work.

Edit: The exact encryption doesn't matter a lot. I'd probably use AES, simply because it's easy to find an implementation and it runs pretty fast, so there's not much reason to use something else.

As far as how the calling code would work, it would be something like this:

```
struct functions { 
     rettype1 (*func1)(args1);
     rettype2 (*func2)(args2);
     rettype3 (*func3)(args3);
     // ...
};

void entry_point(key_type key) { 
     functions f;
     decrypt(data_block);
     f.func1 = data_block.offset1;
     f.func2 = data_block.offset2;
     // ...
     return f;
}
```

In the calling code you'd have initialization something like:

```
functions f = entry_point(myKey);
```

and then calling a function would be something like:

```
f.whatever(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

In essence, you're re-creating a small piece of object oriented programming, and having your entry point return an "object" of sorts, with the DLL's real functions as "member functions" of that "object".

As far as getting the checksum goes, I haven't thought through it in a lot of detail. Basically just just want the address where the executable is stored. You can walk through modules with VirtualQuery, or you can use GetModuleHandle(NULL).

Comment: Thanks Jerry! These are good ideas. For option #1, do you have some tips for how to encrypt my code? Does this mean I couldn't simply give them a c++ header file or list of method signatures? I'm curious what the calling code would look like.

For option #2, that's basically what I have now--a simple key that is passed to authorize access. Good to know a debugger could easily sniff that out. How can I get the checksum of the calling exec from the DLL?

Comment: Hi Jerry -- I get your encryption idea in theory, but I haven't figured out how to completely tie it together. Would I encrypt my library after I compile it? Would this impact C# callers or objective C callers?

The checksum shows some promise though. I can figure out which execs have loaded my library and then verify the checksum of those execs with a known value.

Comment: @user979133: Yes, you'd encrypt the library after you compile it, then include the result as a binary resource. To use it, you'd have to load the resource, decrypt it, then cast the result to a pointer to function (and hope DEP doesn't kick in and stop it from working). One of the ideas was to *avoid* checking things against a known value, which is usually *quite* trivial to find and work around.

Comment: Protection is only as strong as its weakest link. In this case, it's the `key` parameter. An attacker merely needs to set a breakpoint on `entry_point` and look at what was passed as the `key` parameter. They can then copy that key to their progarm.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yup -- "Just for an obvious example, if somebody runs the authorized program under a debugger they can see what key is passed, and simply re-use it." Using a checksum of the executable won't actually stop a determined attacker either -- it just makes it a little less obvious which code to look at to find the key. If it'll execute, however, it's only security by obscurity -- breakable by definition.

Comment: @Jerry Oops, sorry, missed that the first time through.

Comment: @RaymondChen: No problem at all. IMO, a point that was well worth repeating.

Comment: The checksum method doesn't require a key to be passed though. What I'm thinking is I can figure out which exec loaded my library, calculate the checksum on the exec, and then match it to a string that's baked in my library. So the only way to hack around this would be to either change the approved list of checksums in my library, or create an exec that has the same checksum as the approved exec. I understand it'll never be 100% safe but I'm cool with good enough ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with access to the dll will be able to inspect it, load it, and get pointers to functions in the dll. I'm not sure you strictly mean dll though as you say:

> FWIW - the DLL will be used on both Mac and Windows.

[Dlls aren't a Mac thing](https://superuser.com/questions/228309/macos-dll-equivalent)--they are a Windows specific implementation of a runtime loaded/linked library. So you're real question, I'm assuming, must simply be about limiting access to a library for only certain 3rd parties. To achieve your goal, some other options may be more appropriate:

- Instead of a dll, compile everything into a single monolothic exe. Run that exe as a service or a second process on the box. Have the 3rd party connect to it through sockets/named pipes/whatever other forms of interprocess communication. Authenticate the users of the service so that only the 3rd party software with the right credentials can access the service. Everyone else gets denied access.
- Create an account for the 3rd party application. The 3rd party application can only run when that account is logged in. Place the dll (or dylib in the case of Mac) in a folder only accessible to that account. Noone else has access to that location, so no other applications can run it barring those run as administrator.

Comment: Thanks Doug! You're correct--I meant library instead of DLL.

Why is it better to have an exe instead of a dll? Is it just more difficult to intercept the authentication codes?

I don't think option #2 would work because an end-user could easily have an admin account.